# T-SQL - wrong query execution plan behaviour

Tags: performance, query-optimization, sql-server-2012

One of our queries degraded after generating load on the DB.

Our query is a join between 3 tables:

1. `Base` table which contain 10 M rows.
2. `EventPerson` table which contain 5000 rows.
3. `EventPerson788` which is empty.

It seems that the optimizer scans the index on the `EventPerson` instead of seek, this the script for replicating the issue:

```
--Create Tables 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BASE](
        [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [IsActive] BIT
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC) 
)ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventPerson](
    [DUID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PersonInvolvedID] [bigint] NULL,

PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DUID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [EventPerson_IDX] ON [dbo].[EventPerson]
(
    [PersonInvolvedID] ASC
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventPerson788](
    [EntryID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [LinkedSuspectID] [bigint] NULL,
    [sourceid] [bigint] NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EntryID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventPerson788] WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK7A34153D3720F84A] 
FOREIGN KEY([sourceid]) REFERENCES [dbo].[EventPerson] ([DUID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventPerson788] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK7A34153D3720F84A]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [EventPerson788_IDX] 
ON [dbo].[EventPerson788] ([LinkedSuspectID] ASC)
GO

--POPOLATE BASE TABLE 
DECLARE @I BIGINT=1 
WHILE (@I<10000000) 
    BEGIN
    begin transaction
    INSERT INTO BASE(ID) VALUES(@I) 
    SET @I+=1
        if (@I%10000=0 )
        begin
    commit;
        end;

    END
go

--POPOLATE EventPerson TABLE 
DECLARE @I BIGINT=1 
WHILE (@I<5000) 
    BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO EventPerson(DUID,PersonInvolvedID) VALUES(@I,(SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM BASE ORDER BY NEWID())) 
        SET @I+=1
        IF(@I%10000=0 )
            COMMIT TRANSACTION ;
    END

GO
```

This the query :

```
select 
    count(EventPerson.DUID) 
from 
    EventPerson  
inner loop join 
    Base on EventPerson.DUID = base.ID 
left outer join 
    EventPerson788 on EventPerson.DUID = EventPerson788.sourceid 
where 
    (EventPerson.PersonInvolvedID = 37909 or 
     EventPerson788.LinkedSuspectID = 37909) 
    AND BASE.IsActive = 1
```

Do you have any idea why the optimizer decides to use index scan instead of index seek?

Workaround that already done :

- Analyze tables and build statistics.
- Rebuild Indices.
- Try the FORCESEEK hint

None of the above persuaded the optimizer to run an index seek on `EventPerson` and seek on the base tables.

Thanks for your help .

Answer (score 2):

The scan is there because of the `or` condition and the outer join against `EventPerson788`.

Either it will return rows from `EventPerson` when `EventPerson.PersonInvolvedID = 37909` **or** when the there exists rows in `EventPerson788` where `EventPerson788.LinkedSuspectID = 37909`. The last part means that every row in `EventPerson` has to be checked against the join.

The fact that `EventPerson788` is empty can not be used by the query optimizer since the query plan is saved to be reused later when there might be matching rows in `EventPerson788`.

Update:

You can rewrite your query using a union all instead of or to get a seek in `EventPerson`.

```
select count(EventPerson.DUID) 
from 
  (
    select EventPerson.DUID
    from EventPerson
    where EventPerson.PersonInvolvedID = 1556 and
          not exists (select * 
                      from EventPerson788 
                      where EventPerson788.LinkedSuspectID = 1556) 
    union all
    select EventPerson788.sourceid
    from EventPerson788
    where EventPerson788.LinkedSuspectID = 1556
  ) as EventPerson  
  inner join BASE  
    on EventPerson.DUID=base.ID 
where
  BASE.IsActive=1
```

[image]

Comment: Mikael , Its a good idea to use union but i'll need to verify our infrastructure supports these kind of queries. Still it's seems that the optimizer act in worng way dont you think so ? thanks for your help.

Comment: @tamirt Perhaps it is an optimization that SQL Server could come up with by it's own and perhaps it is too far fetched. I don't know enough about the rewrites done by the query optimizer to answer that.

Comment: Mikael , Thanks for the answers we try to work around from here .

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're asking SQL Server to **count the rows** of the `EventPerson` table - so why do you expect a seek to be better than a scan here?

For a `COUNT`, the SQL Server optimizer will almost always use a **scan** - it needs to count the rows, after all - all of them... it will do a clustered index scan, if no other non-nullable columns are indexed.

If you have an index on a small, non-nullable column (e.g. on a `ID INT` or something like that), it would probably do a scan on that index instead (less data to read to count all rows).

But in general: **seek** is great for selecting **one or a few rows** - but it sucks if you're dealing with **all rows** (like for a count)

You can easily observe this behavior if you're using the `AdventureWorks` sample database.

When doing a `COUNT(*)` on the `Sales.SalesOrderDetail` table which has over 120000 rows like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
```

then you'll get an index scan on `IX_SalesOrderDetail_ProductID` - it just doesn't pay off to do seeks on over 120000 entries!

However, if you do the same operation on a smaller set of data, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
WHERE ProductID = 897
```

then you get back 2 rows out of all of them - and SQL Server will now use an **index seek** on that same index.

Comment: Hi marc ,  thanks for the quick answer . when we eliminate the OR condition it starts to use index seek ( both eventperson & base tables are joined by the pk ). BTW after the count the application run row by row for each id returned the count is just to verify that there are records to handle.